# Upgrade my hadoop to latest stable version

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to upgrade my Hadoop infrastructure installed on Ubuntu 14.04 from hadoop-2.2.0-stable to hadoop-2.6.0-stable. Am I supposed to remove my previous version of hadoop and install a fresh copy or is it possible to move to a newer version without loosing any data? Any help is appreciated